# Absolute position with text at an angle

Tags: html, css

I have header, which displays at an angle and has such class

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.example2 {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;

}

.example {
    position:absolute;
    color:#24c245;
    align:right;
    bottom:50%;
    right:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
  -ms-transform:rotate(-20deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotate(20deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-20deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotate(-20deg);
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="example2">
    <img src="images/achievement.png">
    <h4 class="example">hlkjlkjsdfasdfsadfasdfasdfasdfasdfhkjl</h4>
</div>
</body>
```

Header could have different length, I thought that it always be on the same place on screen but it constantly moving and position depends of length. I can't understand why.

Comment: Can you post your html as well and be more specific about the desired output?

Comment: without HTML code, we are only guessing.  Please provide HTML or make >> **[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/)** << so we can make better answers.

Comment: I've added html example, I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that it always be on the same place on screen

If  you want it to be always at the same place relative to the window, use `fixed` positioning instead of `absolute`.

`absolute` positioned elements are positioned relative to the first parent having position other than `static`, only if no such parent element exists it'll be positioned relative to window..

*Update: As per comments this issue can be fixed using `transform-origin` property*

Comment: I mean that it changes position depending on length of header if length is const it stays still

Comment: What do you mean by the 'length of header'? Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Yc3th/) with your code.. as far as i can see it's working fine.. header text stays at the same place when window is resized..

Comment: I mean if it had only 5 symbols in header it was there https://www.dropbox.com/s/pjd6yt67wlipit9/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-30%20at%2019.01.49.png (header is green in center), but if it has 15 symbols it goes here https://www.dropbox.com/s/ubn5nn8hlmztaka/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-30%20at%2019.02.09.png

Comment: You couuld fix this using `transform-origin` property

Answer (score 0):

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/hamoj/1/edit)**

```
position:absolute;    /* or 'fixed' if needed*/
text-align:center;
bottom:50%;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:0 auto;

transform:rotate:(50deg);
-o-transform:rotate(50deg); 
-ms-transform:rotate(50deg); 
-moz-transform:rotate(50deg); 
-webkit-transform:rotate(50deg);
```

Comment: @vZ10 have you taken a look at the demo I provided? http://jsbin.com/hamoj/2/edit *"Nothing changed"* is not quite true from my perspective (change my code with yours ...)

Comment: @vZ10 can you setup a proper jsBin that reflects the 'issue' ? Might be much clearer what you're trying to achieve?